# Render entire HTML page from Flask using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask, axios

My web app on the backend is Flask and I use Jinja2 and wtforms to dynamically generate content.

The main page that is generated is a table of all the sales for any given month. At the top of the table, there are select fields used to filter the sales, Month, Director, and Account Manager.

When someone selects an account manager, for example, from the Account Manager dropdown, I would like an event to be triggered that sends a "get" request back to the server with the selected account manager. The server would then generate the new filtered content and send the HTML page back to be rendered on the client.

I want the dynamic rendering to remain on the backend. I added an event listener to the Account Manager select field and then tried to use Axios to send an ajax call to the server using a "get" request, which works. I get the entire HTML document back as data.

My question is, how do I now render that entire HTML document returned to Axios? Or, is there a better way to do this?

I know I could easily create a form with those filter elements and then a submit button to send a "post" request back to the server and it will work. But, I really would like to send a "get" request when a select field changes without having the user click a button.

Comment: Normally you would only send a partial not  full page for ajax content. Then insert that partial in the container it needs to be displayed in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this on my own. I kind of answered it in my last paragraph of the question. A solution is to simply create a form that includes the filter select elements. I then added an event listener on each of the select elements. The function for the event listener then calls submit on the form. Pretty simple.